# How to solve the problem of unmet dependencies on Ubuntu-22.04

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, upgrade, maas

Basically, when I am trying to upgrade my ubuntu I got this error saying :

```
christian@christian-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-remote-desktop gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs libayatana-appindicator3-1 libinput-bin libinput10
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsemanage-common libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libudev1 libwacom-bin
  libwacom-common mutter node-ajv node-constants-browserify node-debbundle-acorn node-errno node-json5 node-mkdirp node-sha.js node-which node-yargs
  node-yargs-parser ntfs-3g passwd rygel sssd-common sssd-krb5 sssd-krb5-common sssd-proxy systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal udev usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xserver-xorg-input-libinput
  yaru-theme-gnome-shell
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
```

So when I run the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get this message:

```
christian@christian-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-yargs-parser : Breaks: node-yargs (< 16.2.0~) but 15.3.1+repack-2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I solve this issue? I'm using ubuntu 22.04

Edit: Output of `apt policy node-yargs-parser`:

```
christian@christian-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ sudo apt policy node-yargs-parser
[sudo] password for christian:
node-yargs-parser:
   Installed: 18.1.3+~15.0.0-1
   Candidate: 21.0.0+~20.2.1-3
   Version table:
      21.0.0+~20.2.1-3 500
         500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
         500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages  *** 18.1.3+~15.0.0-1 100
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status christian@christian-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$
```

Comment: Please add the contents of the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ file to your question with EDIT.

Comment: How can I find those contents @David

Comment: The man page from the OS has this info. https://linux.die.net/man/5/sources.list

Comment: How did you install `node-yargs-parser`, and which version is installed (run `apt policy node-yargs-parser`)? These pieces of information might be important to understand the problem.

Comment: Do you see the problem? The official version for [Jammy is 21.0.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/node-yargs-parser) - you have an old version installed that does not match your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thank you so much @ArturMeinild, It solves the problem I can't see the red flag no more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, reinstalling the correct version of `node-yargs-parser` should solve the issue. Run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall node-yargs-parser
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ArturMeinild, This helps me out.